# View the console output of a running Java program, from another Java app

Tags: java, service, console

I have a program made in Java, which you want to configure as an operating system service. The program reads data received by socket, which processes and stores it. It also logs errors and finally prints the information flow all the time in console to observe its operation.

After setting it up as a service, a need arose.

How do I view the print activity in console, if the application is in the background and therefore the console is not open?

Is there a way to view the console output of that application?

It occurred to me, if it is possible to create another Java application to read and print the console output of the created service. Would that solve the problem?

Comment: This is really an OS question rather than a Java question. Generally, only the process that started your app will be able to read its stdout. For services, hopefully the OS feature that starts your service also uses some kind of logging that you might hook into. Otherwise, you'll have to use some other form of IPC (like for example named pipes on unix)

Comment: How about using a logging framework ( [log4j](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/), [logback](https://logback.qos.ch/), etc, maybe with [slf4j](https://www.slf4j.org/) if you want to switch the logging implementation ) instead of writing to `stdout`?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your comments, after researching a little more thoroughly, according to your suggestions, i developed an IPC communication system via Sockets, in which, an swing application connects to the service and requests Every 2 seconds the required information and the sample in the app

Comment: While it is great that you are posting an answer to your own question, this answer would not be useful for a future visitor having a similar issue.  Can you clarify this further?